# Difference in display of inline elements when toggled programmatically and declared inline on WebKit

Tags: jquery, css, html, webkit

**[jsFiddle reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/YumVZ/)**

I’ve got some `div` elements that are nested beneath a `span`. I need the inline behavior of the outer elements and the block behavior of the inner. I can declare a class on the `.outer` span parent that sets the display of `.inner` as `none`. If I declare this in the HTML itself all of the spans collapse as expected into a single line. However, if I toggle the `.collapse` style with JavaScript (jQuery `.toggleClass`, in this case). I still get a mysterious line break, i.e. even if the container for the block-level elements is not displayed, the browser doesn't reclaim the vertical space.

This only happens in WebKit (Chrome and Safari). Firefox behaves as I’d expect. I haven’t bothered to try this in IE.

An explanation and/or a work-around would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Spans</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">//</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(evt) {
      $(".toggle").click(function(evt) {
        $(this).closest(".outer").toggleClass("collapsed");
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Helvetica; }
    span { padding: 0 0.5em; margin-right: 0.5em; outline: solid 1px #ccc; }
    .outer.collapsed .inner {
      display: none;
    }
    .outer.collapsed .open:after {
      content: "…";
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2><code>.outer.collapsed</code> toggled by jQuery</h2>
  <div><span>The following should display inline when collapsed: </span>
    <span class="outer">
      <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
      <span class="open">[</span>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
      </div>
      <span class="close">]</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <h2><code>.outer.collapsed</code> Declared inline</h2>
  <div><span>The following should display inline when collapsed: </span>
    <span class="outer collapsed">
      <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
      <span class="open">[</span>
      <div class="inner">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
      </div>
      <span class="close">]</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div>`-s inside of `<span>`-s are invalid.. if you change that - http://jsfiddle.net/YumVZ/1/

Comment: Zoltan, thanks for your help. I could make `.outer` a `div`. However, I need the button and `span.open` to display on the same line as `The following should…` text. Adding `display: inline` to the `.outer` selector (as a `div`) displays the same behavior. The inconsistency is the difference in behavior when the `.collapsed` class is specified in mark-up verus programmatically. I think this is a WebKit bug. I’d be happy to hear otherwise, though.

Comment: Updated with the `.outer` inline - http://jsfiddle.net/YumVZ/2/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. This is clever. However, the incorrect behavior still happens when `.outer` is _not_ initially collapsed (i.e. it doesn’t declare `.collapsed` in the mark-up). I guess I could toggle them with JavaScript upon initial load. That’s a bummer, though, if I need to loop through potentially thousands of them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ugly, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YumVZ/3/) seems to work. There is something about having the `collapsed` class not initially declared in the mark-up that triggers this layout bug.